# NSUserDefaults in swift for saving Array of String for TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

Hi I have a `tableview` and this is my code in `MyItemTableViewController` Class

```
var itemList = [String]()

@IBAction func saveItemToList (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let AddNewItemViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! addItemTableViewController

    let name = AddNewItemViewController.itemName

    if name == "" {

    }
    else {
        itemList.append(name!)

        let indexToInsert = itemList.count == 0 ? 0 : itemList.count - 1

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexToInsert, inSection: 0)

        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }

}
```

How can I save my array using `NSUserDefaults` I was trying some ways but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `itemList` Array like this way.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(itemList, forKey: "items")
defaults.synchronize()
```

When you need to extract from `NSUserDefaults` you can extract it like this

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let items = defaults.objectForKey("items") as? [String] {
    print(items)
}
```

Or you can also use `stringArrayForKey`.

```
if let items = defaults.stringArrayForKey("items") {
    print(items)
}
```

For more detail about `NSUserDefaults` read this [tutorial](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)

**Edit:** The problem is you are trying to add `[String]` object inside Sting array, that not possible, if you want to merge two array then write like this.

```
if let items = defaults.stringArrayForKey("items") {
    self.itemList = self.itemList + items
}
```

Comment: Im trying to append items to itemList but it said Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String' i don't no what i should do

Comment: i have another quotation if you don't mind , if i clicked on particular cell , i need the title of that cell be the header of the second view controller

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Comment: Can you add the new Post with you navigation code that will help me to understand what you have try.

Comment: Don't understand what you want, also there is no code of navigation, It is batter if you add new post.

Comment: sorry i don't understand you what is code of navigation

Comment: is it this ?         override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "SaveSection" {
        sectionName = addSection.text
    
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "Cancel"{
        }
    }

Comment: yes that was just create one String object in your `destintaionViewController` after that pass its value in `prepareForSegue`, now use this string variable in `viewDidLoad` of `destintaionViewController`